# Removing an empty array from an object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this `JSON` object **myFilters**:

```
{"filters":
      {"role":"","jobs":[]}
}
```

I can correctly remove the empty object from it with this function clean (`myFilters`):

```
function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (
      obj[propName] === null ||
      obj[propName] === undefined ||
      obj[propName] === ""
    ) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
```

So now, my **myFilters** object becomes:

```
{"filters":
    { "jobs":[] }
}
```

How can I now remove the empty array and the key from my `JSON` object?

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more condition like

```
function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (
      obj[propName] === null ||
      obj[propName] === undefined ||
      obj[propName] === "" ||
      Array.isArray(obj[propName]) && obj[propName].length === 0
    ) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should check the type of property before check its value by the
> **typeof**
>
> The **jobs** property is an **object** and you can check its value by its
> **length**. it is empty if its **length** equals to 0.

```
function clean(obj) {

    for (var propName in obj) {

        if (typeof (obj[propName]) == 'object') {

            if (obj[propName].length == 0) {
                delete obj[propName];
            }

        } else {

            if (
                obj[propName] === null ||
                obj[propName] === undefined ||
                obj[propName] === ""
            ) {
                delete obj[propName];
            }

        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Saveli Tomac's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374552/removing-an-empty-array-from-an-object-with-javascript/59374613#59374613), so I upvoted that. Let me show you an additional shortening on the original solution also.

As it's been stated that you need to check 2 more things if you are looking for an empty array. So what about checking `null`, `undefined` and `''` values easier?

```js
if (!undefined) { console.log('undefined needs to be deleted') };
if (!null) { console.log('null needs to be deleted') };
if (!'') { console.log(`'' needs to be deleted`) };
```

Checking `Array.length` if it has `0` value can be also shorter just like the following:

```js
const array1 = [];
const array2 = [1,2,3];
if (!array1.length) { console.log('array1 has 0 length') };
if (!array2.length) { console.log('array2 has 0 length') };
```

So based on those code snippets you can have an additional shortening just like the following:

```js
// extended with other types for the demo
let myObject = { "filters": { "role": "", "jobs": [], "nullValue": null, "undefinedIsHere": undefined, "arrayWithValue": [1,2,3], "stringValue": "hello", "numberishere": 123 } };

const clean = (obj) => {
  for (let propName in obj) {
    if (
      !obj[propName] ||
      Array.isArray(obj[propName]) && !obj[propName].length
    ) { delete obj[propName] };
  }
}

clean(myObject.filters);
console.log(myObject);
```

Or with a 1️⃣ liner:

```js
// extended with other types for the demo
let myObject = { "filters": { "role": "", "jobs": [], "nullValue": null, "undefinedIsHere": undefined, "arrayWithValue": [1,2,3], "stringValue": "hello", "numberishere": 123 } };

const clean = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(propName => (!obj[propName] || Array.isArray(obj[propName]) && !obj[propName].length) && delete obj[propName]);
}

clean(myObject.filters);
console.log(myObject);
```

Read further here:

1. [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
2. [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
var filterObj = {
 "filters": {
  "role": "",
  "jobs": []
 }
};

for (var i in filterObj) {
  for (var j in filterObj[i]) {
   if ((filterObj[i][j] === null) ||
        (filterObj[i][j] === undefined) ||
        (filterObj[i][j].length === 0)) {
        delete filterObj[i][j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(filterObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName) && 
      obj[propName] === null ||
      obj[propName] === undefined ||
      obj[propName] === "" || 
      (Array.isArray(obj[propName]) && obj[propName].length <= 0)
    ) {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Saveli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12400636/saveli-tomac)'s answer should work fine. Here's an alternative approach you can use to achieve the same result.

```js
const object = {
  "filters": {
    "role": "",
    "jobs": [],
    "foo": undefined,
    "baz": null,
    "bar": {},
    "moreJobs": ['1', '2']
  }
}

const result = {
  filters: Object.keys(object.filters).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (
      object.filters[key] !== null &&
      object.filters[key] !== undefined &&
      object.filters[key] !== '' &&
      typeof object.filters[key] === 'object' && Object.keys(object.filters[key]).length > 0
    ) {
      acc[key] = object.filters[key];
    }

    return acc;
  }, {})
};

console.log(result);
```